# Hierarchical transformer for document classification: model implementation error, extracting attention weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transformer-model, attention-model

I am trying to implement a hierarchical transformer for document classification in Keras/tensorflow, in which:

(1) a word-level transformer produces a representation of each sentence, and attention weights for each word, and,

(2) a sentence-level transformer uses the outputs from (1) to produce a representation of each document, and attention weights for each sentence, and finally,

(3) the document representations produced by (2) are used to classify documents (in the following example, as belonging or not belonging to a given class).

I am attempting to model the classifier on Yang et al.'s approach here ([https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./hovy/papers/16HLT-hierarchical-attention-networks.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E./hovy/papers/16HLT-hierarchical-attention-networks.pdf)), but replacing the GRU and attention layers with transformers.

I am using Apoorv Nandan's transformer implementation from https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_with_transformer/.

I have two issues for which I would be grateful for the community's help:

**(1) I get an error in the upper (sentence) level model that I can't resolve (details and code below)**

**(2) I don't know how to extract the word- and sentence-level attention weights, and value advice on how best to do this.**

I am new to both Keras and this forum, so apologies for obvious mistakes and thank you in advance for any help.

Here is a reproducible example, indicating where I encounter errors:

First, establish the multi-head attention, transformer, and token/position embedding layers, after Nandan.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class MultiHeadSelfAttention(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads=8):
        super(MultiHeadSelfAttention, self).__init__()
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        if embed_dim % num_heads != 0:
            raise ValueError(
                f"embedding dimension = {embed_dim} should be divisible by number of heads = {num_heads}"
            )
        self.projection_dim = embed_dim // num_heads
        self.query_dense = layers.Dense(embed_dim)
        self.key_dense = layers.Dense(embed_dim)
        self.value_dense = layers.Dense(embed_dim)
        self.combine_heads = layers.Dense(embed_dim)

    def attention(self, query, key, value):
        score = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b=True)
        dim_key = tf.cast(tf.shape(key)[-1], tf.float32)
        scaled_score = score / tf.math.sqrt(dim_key)
        weights = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_score, axis=-1)
        output = tf.matmul(weights, value)
        return output, weights

    def separate_heads(self, x, batch_size):
        x = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, -1, self.num_heads, self.projection_dim))
        return tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])

    def call(self, inputs):
        # x.shape = [batch_size, seq_len, embedding_dim]
        batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
        query = self.query_dense(inputs)  # (batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim)
        key = self.key_dense(inputs)  # (batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim)
        value = self.value_dense(inputs)  # (batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim)
        query = self.separate_heads(
            query, batch_size
        )  # (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len, projection_dim)
        key = self.separate_heads(
            key, batch_size
        )  # (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len, projection_dim)
        value = self.separate_heads(
            value, batch_size
        )  # (batch_size, num_heads, seq_len, projection_dim)
        attention, weights = self.attention(query, key, value)
        attention = tf.transpose(
            attention, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3]
        )  # (batch_size, seq_len, num_heads, projection_dim)
        concat_attention = tf.reshape(
            attention, (batch_size, -1, self.embed_dim)
        )  # (batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim)
        output = self.combine_heads(
            concat_attention
        )  # (batch_size, seq_len, embed_dim)
        return output

class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout_rate, name=None):
        super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.att = MultiHeadSelfAttention(embed_dim, num_heads)
        self.ffn = keras.Sequential(
            [layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        attn_output = self.att(inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)

class TokenAndPositionEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim, name=None):
        super(TokenAndPositionEmbedding, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.token_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim)
        self.pos_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=maxlen, output_dim=embed_dim)

    def call(self, x):
        maxlen = tf.shape(x)[-1]
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=maxlen, delta=1)
        positions = self.pos_emb(positions)
        x = self.token_emb(x)
        return x + positions
```

For the purpose of this example, the data are 10,000 documents, each truncated to 15 sentences, each sentence with a maximum of 60 words, which are already converted to integer tokens 1-1000.

X is a 3-D tensor (10000, 15, 60) containing these tokens. y is a 1-D tensor containing the classes of the documents (1 or 0). For the purpose of this example there is no relation between X and y.

The following produces the example data:

```
max_docs = 10000
max_sentences = 15
max_words = 60

X = tf.random.uniform(shape=(max_docs, max_sentences, max_words), minval=1, maxval=1000, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32, seed=1)

y = tf.random.uniform(shape=(max_docs,), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32, seed=1)
```

Here I attempt to construct the word level encoder, after https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_with_transformer/:

```
# Lower level (produce a representation of each sentence):

embed_dim = 100 # Embedding size for each token
num_heads = 2  # Number of attention heads
ff_dim = 64  # Hidden layer size in feed forward network inside transformer
L1_dense_units = 100 # Size of the sentence-level representations output by the word-level model
dropout_rate = 0.1
vocab_size=1000

word_input = layers.Input(shape=(max_words,), name='word_input') 
word_embedding = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen=max_words, vocab_size=vocab_size, 
                                           embed_dim=embed_dim, name='word_embedding')(word_input) 
word_transformer = TransformerBlock(embed_dim=embed_dim, num_heads=num_heads, ff_dim=ff_dim, 
                                    dropout_rate=dropout_rate, name='word_transformer')(word_embedding)
word_pool = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(name='word_pooling')(word_transformer) 
word_drop = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate,name='word_drop')(word_pool)
word_dense = layers.Dense(L1_dense_units, activation="relu",name='word_dense')(word_drop)
word_encoder = keras.Model(word_input, word_dense) 

word_encoder.summary()
```

It looks as though this word encoder works as intended to produce a representation of each sentence. Here, run on the 1st document, it produces a tensor of shape (15, 100), containing the vectors representing each of 15 sentences:

```
word_encoder(X[0]).shape
```

My problem is in connecting this to the higher (sentence) level model, to produce document representations.

**I get error "NotImplementedError" when trying to apply the word encoder to each sentence in a document. I would be grateful for any help in fixing this issue, since the error message is not informative as to the specific problem.**

After applying the word encoder to each sentence, the goal is to apply another transformer to produce attention weights for each sentence, and a document-level representation with which to perform classification. I can't determine whether this part of the model will work because of the error above.

**Finally, I would like to extract word- and sentence-level attention weights for each document, and would be grateful for advice on how to do so.**

Thank you in advance for any insight.

```
# Upper level (produce a representation of each document):

L2_dense_units = 100

sentence_input = layers.Input(shape=(max_sentences, max_words), name='sentence_input') 

# This is the line producing "NotImplementedError":
sentence_encoder = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(word_encoder, name='sentence_encoder')(sentence_input) 

sentence_transformer = TransformerBlock(embed_dim=L1_dense_units, num_heads=num_heads, ff_dim=ff_dim, 
                               dropout_rate=dropout_rate, name='sentence_transformer')(sentence_encoder)
sentence_dense = layers.TimeDistributed(Dense(int(L2_dense_units)),name='sentence_dense')(sentence_transformer)
sentence_out = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(sentence_dense)
preds = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='sentence_output')(sentence_out)

model = keras.Model(sentence_input, preds) 
model.summary()
```

Comment: Have u implemented this model successfully? I really need this code. my email: rahman.jalayer@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I got NotImplementedError as well while trying to do the same thing as you. The thing is Keras's TimeDistributed layer needs to know its inner custom layer's output shapes. So you should add compute_output_shape method to your custom layers.

In your case MultiHeadSelfAttention, TransformerBlock and TokenAndPositionEmbedding layers should include:

```
class MultiHeadSelfAttention(layers.Layer):
    ...
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        # it does not change the shape of its input
        return input_shape

class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    ...
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        # it does not change the shape of its input
        return input_shape

class TokenAndPositionEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    ...
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        # it changes the shape from (batch_size, maxlen) to (batch_size, maxlen, embed_dim)
        return input_shape + (self.pos_emb.output_dim,)
```

After you add these methods you should be able to run your code.

As for your second question, I am not sure but maybe you can return the "weights" variable that is returned from MultiHeadSelfAttention's attention method in call methods of both MultiHeadSelfAttention and TransformerBlock. So that you can access it where you build your model.